# Does 35 to 70 mm blow up lose a part of the image?

Tags: film-techniques, projection

The [Wikipedia article on 70 mm film](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/70_mm_film) has a section about the process of converting 35 mm film to 70 mm, or "blow-up".

Since 35 mm and 70 mm have different aspect ratios, does that mean that a part of the original 35 mm image is lost in the process? The examples shown in the article do not seem to have black bands at the edges. 
Or, would theater projectors require a special equipment to project blow-up 70 mm film?

Comment: I can't find any evidence to support the theory, but I would suspect that anamorphic projection would cover the differences. Mainly it was done to be able to use the multi-channel audio; which of course is a moot point these days.

Comment: I doubt there is any definitive answer to this. This is/was a pretty rare thing to do, and even common things in the film industry have struggled with standardized methods to accomplish them.